# Losing Custom Formats on a List/View

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, custom

We created a custom list/view in SharePoint 2010. After we created the list/view we went into SharePoint Designer and changed the title of the view, the font color and size, etc.

Next we deployed our site to staging and all of the custom changes/formats made in SharePoint Designer to the list/view were gone on the staging site.

Is there a setting that we are missing some where in SP Designer or during the deployment process that we need to set or is it something else that we are not doing right??? If anyone could give any guidance on this I would REALLY, REALLY appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

What page type are you modifying the pages in. Are you doing it in a wiki style page or a blank web part page. The wiki style pages can take out your code/changes. For the items such as your font color, size, etc. I would highly recommend you use a custom stylesheet and reference that from the pages instead of adding them inline or to the header. As for the title you could just add a content editor web part to the pages and modify that instead of doing code. Then you could just hide the web part header by setting the chrome on the web part to none.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance I'm kinda new to this so I'm not sure what you mean by wiki, but I do know it's not a web part page. From my little pea brain perspective we created a custom list in SharePoint and when we modified the view to change the fonts and title we used Designer. Unfortunately we don't use designer to it's fullest potential just for the basics. So is there another way to approach this??? Also is this a known issue???

Comment: SharePoint 2010 has a couple of different versions of page types. If you started with a Team Site template you would have started with Wiki pages. These types of pages do not have separate web part zones. If you created the site from the blank site template you would have started with a standard blank web part page. With a left and right zone. However this is probably irrelevant know that I have re-read your question. How are you moving the custom list between dev and staging?

Comment: Good question. The farm administrator is doing it and he is using some sort of import/export process (nothing custom) that is provided by SharePoint. Also I see your point about the team site template and the blank site template, which is good to know (cause I did not know that). And we did build the site from the team site template and then built the list afterwards on that team site.